# adding a recursive folder structure to XML serialisation

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a c# project that serializes a list of objects out to xml.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class collection {
    private List<item> _items = new List<item>();

    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<item> items {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
    public class item {
}
```

the xml output is then

```
<collection>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
</collection>
```

what I would like is to add the option of folders&subfolders so items can be grouped together while still being able to go in the root node.

```
<collection>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <folder>
        <item/>
        <item/>
    </folder>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <folder>
        <item/>
        <item/>
        <folder>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <item/>
</collection>
```

Can anyone advise a clean way of doing this while continuing to generate the xml output using serialised objects?

Comment: You need to parse using folder instead of item.  You could get the parent of item but I don't personally like using the parent property.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be the class structure.

```
public class Folder2
{
}

public class Folder
{
    public Folder2 folder { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public List<Folder> folder { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Collection collection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looking at this I believe it would the make the folders mandatory (instead of optional) and also always fixed at two levels deep.

Comment: You can use Optional attribute for that

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error I managed to get the functionality I was after.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class collection {
    private List<treeEntry> _entries = new List<treeEntry>();

    [XmlElement("item", typeof(item))]
    [XmlElement("folder", typeof(folder))]
    public List<treeEntry> entries {
        get { return _entries; }
    }
}

public abstract class treeEntry { }

[Serializable]
public class folder : treeEntry {
    private List<treeEntry> _entries = new List<treeEntry>();

    public folder() { }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("item", typeof(item))]
    [XmlElement("folder", typeof(folder))]
    public List<treeEntry> entries {
        get { return _entries; }
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class item : treeEntry { }


public class mytest {
    public static void main() {
        collection col = new collection();
        col.entries.Add(new item());
        col.entries.Add(new item());

        var folder1 = new folder() { name = "someFolder" };
        folder1.entries.Add(new item());
        var folder2 = new folder() { name = "anotherFolder" };
        folder1.entries.Add(folder2);
        folder1.entries.Add(new item());
        folder2.entries.Add(new item());

        col.entries.Add(folder1);
        col.entries.Add(new folder());
        col.entries.Add(new item());


        XmlSerializer sers = new XmlSerializer(typeof(collection));

        //serialise
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("testoutput.xml", false, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            XmlWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            sers.Serialize(xw, col);
        }

        //deserialise
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("testoutput.xml", FileMode.Open);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
        collection newcol = (collection)sers.Deserialize(reader);

        //output to console
        sers.Serialize(Console.Out, newcol);
    }
}
```

which produced the desired output

```
<collection>
    <item />
    <item />
    <folder name="someFolder">
        <item />
        <folder name="anotherFolder">
            <item />
        </folder>
        <item />
    </folder>
    <folder />
    <item />
</collection>
```